# How do I get the range in one dataframe column based on duplicate items in two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains three columns: 'sequences', 'smiles' and 'labels'. Some of the rows have the same string entries in the 'sequences' and 'smiles' column, but a different float value in the 'labels' column. For duplicate sequences and smiles, I would like the get the range of values of the 'labels' column for those duplicate rows, which will be stored in a fourth column. I intend to reject rows, which have a range above a certain value.

I have made a dataframe that contains all the duplicate values:

```
duplicate_df = pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby(['sequence', 'smiles']) if len(g) > 1)
```

How do I get the range of the labels from the df?

Is there something like this I can do?

```
duplicate_df.groupby(['Target_sequence', 'processed_SMILES']).range()
```

My duplicate_df looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Label': {86468: 55700.0,
  86484: 55700.0,
  86508: 55700.0,
  124549: 55690.0,
  124588: 55690.0},
 'Target_sequence': {86468: 'AAPYLKTKFICVTPTTCSNTIDLPMSPRTLDSLMQFGNGEGAEPSAGGQF',
  86484: 'AAPYLKTKFICVTPTTCSNTIDLPMSPRTLDSLMQFGNGEGAEPSAGGQF',
  86508: 'AAPYLKTKFICVTPTTCSNTIDLPMSPRTLDSLMQFGNGEGAEPSAGGQF',
  124549: 'AAPYLKTKFICVTPTTCSNTIDLPMSPRTLDSLMQFGNGEGAEPSAGGQF',
  124588: 'AAPYLKTKFICVTPTTCSNTIDLPMSPRTLDSLMQFGNGEGAEPSAGGQF'},
 'processed_SMILES': {86468: 'CCOC(=O)[NH+]1CC[NH+](C(=O)c2ccc(-n3c(=S)[n-]c4ccccc4c3=O)cc2)CC1',
  86484: 'C[NH+]1CC[NH+](Cc2nc3ccccc3c(=O)n2Cc2nc(-c3ccccc3F)cs2)CC1',
  86508: 'C[NH+]1CC[NH+](Cc2nc3ccccc3c(=O)n2Cc2nc(-c3cccc([N+](=O)[O-])c3)cs2)CC1',
  124549: 'C[NH+]1CC[NH+](Cc2nc3ccccc3c(=O)n2Cc2nc(-c3cccc([N+](=O)[O-])c3)cs2)CC1',
  124588: 'CCOC(=O)[NH+]1CC[NH+](C(=O)c2ccc(-n3c(=S)[n-]c4ccccc4c3=O)cc2)CC1'}})
```

For example, duplicate rows where the items are the same I would like to have 0 in the 'range' column.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std()` is a valid aggregation function for [group-by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) object. Therefore, after creating your `df` with the duplicated data, you can try:

```
duplicate_df.groupby(['Target_sequence', 'processed_SMILES'])['labels'].std()
```

Edit:

This is a nice opportunity to use [pd.NamedAgg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) which was released in version 0.25:

```
df.groupby(['Target_sequence','processed_SMILES']).agg(Minimum = pd.NamedAgg(column='Label',aggfunc='min'),
                                                   Maximum = pd.NamedAgg(column='Label',aggfunc='max'))
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, range is more meaningful than standard deviation.

Comment: Edited in answer

Comment: I get this error: `SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported`

Comment: You are right, thank you for highlighting that, it's been solved with NamedAgg